# What does "necessarily" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the sentence in bold mean "**Is it necessary that the USD has to show the same status as it has in the past years**"?

> "But I think more fundamentally you have what I touch on, which is this global thinking about currencies. If you are a global asset allocator, the status of the U.S. dollar is really being questioned. **Is it necessarily the currency that justifies the same status as it has in the past years**? I think strategically you can make the case that the dollar could see its status revisited downwards which would benefit the euro, probably it's benefiting not only the euro, but also the Chinese currency," Saint-George said.

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/08/28/us-dollar-status-in-question-euro-hits-two-and-half-year-high.html

Comment: It is just bad writing or sloppy impromptu speech.... "see its status revisited downwards".

Comment: But approaching the words with an ounce of forgiveness, "Is the dollar *guaranteed* to remain the same stable currency it has  been heretofore?"

Answer (score 0):

> "**Is it necessary that the USD has to show the same status as it has in the past years**"?

The word "**necessary**" refers to the whole clause "*that the USD has to show the same status as it has in the past years*".

The point of the question is to find out the answer to whether *[the USD has to show the same status as it has in the past years]* is necessary!

Comment: I don't think your reading makes that mess of a sentence any clearer. The previous sentence stated "the status of the U.S. dollar is really being questioned".  Taking your paraphrase: "Should it necessarily be the currency [the US Dollar] (or something else) that justifies the same status [of the US dollar] as it [the US Dollar] has in the past years?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I've changed my thoughts on this matter after I've reread it several times.